# Why is Chrome telling me that localhost refused to connect?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I'm new to javascript. Whenever I want to run my program from vs code, I click F5 and then select chrome. As this took a little more time, I thought I could edit the launch.json file. But when I used the suggestion vs code offered me, Chrome says that local host refused to connect. I don't what I did wrong. Can you help me?
My JavaScript file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  

</head>
<body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World!");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My launch.json file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running a web server on port 8080? What VSC extensions do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VSCode marketplace there is an extension called "Live Server":

(available here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) that will allow you to start your code in a server. Once you get it from the marketplace, you can right-click and select "Open with Live Server" in the HTML file to start your code.

It will begin on 5500 or 5501 (but that can be changed later in settings). This extension is one of many options but it works really well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I downloaded it. I tried out changing the port number to 5500 and that worked. So if anyone has this problem try this.

Comment: After playing around with it, I figured out that you have to start the live server. Then, you have to use the port mentioned in the message that pops up on the bottom right part of the screen.

Comment: The port that live server uses is dynamic. So if you want a port that will remain constant all the time, you will have to set a static port in the VSCode settings.